# Do not redirect to the dynamic url

Tags: python, django

Why can't I go to the dynamic url like **"*http://127.0.0.1:8000/movie/xyz*"** with my code?  `xyz` is movie name. Demo is my model's name.

This is my view.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render 
from .models import Demo 

def home(request):
    movie_list = Demo.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'home.html', {movie_list': movie_list,})

def movie_detail(request,title):
    detail = Demo.objects.get(title=title)
    return render(request, 'detail.html', {'detail': detail})
```

urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from netflix.views import home,movie_detail

urlpatterns = [url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
               url(r'^movie', home),
               url(r'^movie/(?P<title>.*)/$', movie_detail, name='movie_detail')]
```

detail.html:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
<div class="card mb-3">
  <img class="card-img-top" src="{{detail.img_url}}" alt="Card image cap">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">{{detail.title}}</h5> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In S.O., it is vital to [accept the post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) that answered your question.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add a terminating `$` to the /movie URL, otherwise it matches everything *starting* with that string.

```
url(r'^movie$', home),
```

Comment: It can work.Thx May I ask antoher question? How can i show the whole div class to html

Comment: i can use {{variable|raw}} in php but i don't know what to do in python

Answer (score 1):

You miss terminate character in `url(r'^movie', home)`

Try this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^movie$', home),
    url(r'^movie/(?P<title>.*)$', movie_detail, name='movie_detail')

]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^movie/(?P<title>\d+)/$', movie_detail, name='movie_detail')
]
```